# Blazor - Using HttpContext in a DLL

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, httpcontext, .net-8.0, system.web

I have a Blazor Server .NET 8 web application that uses HttpContext for some tasks. At first, I can access HttpContext without any problem, then the code executes a second time (pre-render?) and HttpContext becomes null.

My application also calls a DLL, which also retrieves HttpContext.Current. I'm obliged to use HttpContext due to corporate criteria, as the DLL has been migrated from .NET Framework to .NET Core.

Thanks in advance.
Max

[EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ra34.png)

I've tried disabling the pre-render or changing my Program.cs but it doesn't work.

Is it possible to use HttpContext? Or do I have to use another library?

Comment: The `HttpContext` is only relevant in Pre-Render mode.  You can't use it in interactive mode.  What "uses HttpContext for some tasks."  The quoted example shows how to to get the authentication information correctly, why must you do it the other way?

Comment: I use HttpContext for retreive User information (IsAuthenticated, Name ,etc..), for redirection and for retreive somes cookie.
All these tasks are done in a DLL, I cant use AuthenticatedState inside of it because all the class and method are static (and i can't change the code of the dll) and AuthenticatedState use async method.

Comment: My guess then is that your library isn't Blazor compatible.